# How to make Indexer case-insensitive

Tags: c#, indexing, case-insensitive

```
string agentLogin = "John";
IAgent agent = agents[agentLogin];
```

Is there a way to make this Indexer case-insensitive??

I'm aware that things like LinQ would easily solve this, but i need the Indexer for the performance.

agents type is an interface with this property:

```
IAgent this[string agentLogin] {get;}
```

And implementation:

```
Public IAgent this [string login]{ get { return agents[login]; }}
```

Comment: The interface does not tell us much. The problem is in the implementation. If you cannot change the implementation of the indexer, then you could try to pass the index as lower case: `IAgent agent = agents[agentLogin.ToLowerInvariant()];`

Comment: Of course this is possible. Can you show your current implementation?

Comment: What is `agents`? can you please post all relevant parts? especially implementation.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: If you instead used a `Dictionary<string, IAgent>`  then you can easily do that.

Comment: If `agents` is a dictionary then you should pass it a comparer such as `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

For the interface you can't explicitly specify case-sensitivity for the indexer. You can make comment and this is all.

But for specific implementation of an interface (in the class which is implements the interface) you definitely can implement indexer in the case-insensitive way with ease.

But, if someone else will create another class which implements the same interface, the implementation of such a class may be done case-sensitive and you (at interface level) could not prevent this.

So, example implementation may be following

```
interface IAgent
{
    string Login { get; }
}

public class Agent : IAgent
{
    public string Login { get; }
    public Agent(string login) => Login = login;
}

interface IAgentsManager
{
    IAgent this[string agentLogin] { get; }

    void Add(IAgent agent);
}

class AgentsManager : IAgentsManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, IAgent> agents = new();

    public IAgent this[string agentLogin]
    {
        get => agents[agentLogin.ToLowerInvariant()];
        set => agents[agentLogin.ToLowerInvariant()] = value;
    }

    public void Add(IAgent agent)
    {
        agents.Add(agent.Login.ToLowerInvariant(), agent);
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IAgentsManager manager = new AgentsManager();
        manager.Add(new Agent("login"));
        manager.Add(new Agent("UPPER_LOGIN"));
        manager.Add(new Agent("MixedLogin"));

        //will throw "An item with the same key has already been added"
        //manager.Add(new Agent("mixedLogin"));

        Console.WriteLine(manager["login"].Login); //login
        Console.WriteLine(manager["LoGin"].Login); //login
        Console.WriteLine(manager["upper_Login"].Login); //UPPER_LOGIN
        Console.WriteLine(manager["MixedLogin"].Login); //MixedLogin
        Console.WriteLine(manager["mixedlogin"].Login); //MixedLogin
    }
}
```

This implementation provides dicitonary-like interface, where the dictionary key is always stored as lower case and indexer also transforms `login` parameter to the lower case before searching in the dictionary.

You can definitely change the storage type and the whole internal logic, but the idea is pretty simple - transform `login` parameter of the indexer to lower case, transform all known `IAgent.Login` to lower case then compare and select the match.

Comment: How can i make in the specific implementation?

Comment: I added example implementation and some additional comments - please see updated answer

Comment: Use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` in the constructor of the dictionary instead of `ToLowerInvariant` when accessing it.